# All installed eclipse versions crashing randomly - windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse

All the eclipse versions installed on my machine have been randomly crashing. I have Mars, Indigo developer 64 bit versions and Luna - JEE 64 bit version. I am running windows 10, java 8 - 64 bit, maven-3.

I have tried adding -vm to point to the jvm.dll in eclipse.ini. I have set -Xms 512m and -Xmx 1024m. Here is eclipse.ini for Mars:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-server
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Xverify:none
-javaagent:plugins/com.zeroturnaround.eclipse.optimizer.plugin_1.0.8/agent/eclipse-optimizer-agent.jar
```

I tried to run eclipse as an administrator. Nothing has worked so far.

Here is the stack/thread dump for the process - http://pastebin.com/3cSjLh2Z

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the reference to the zeroturnaround plugin and see if that helps.

Comment: I have downloaded a fresh copy of neon and it seems to be working fine for now but I'll try your suggestion if it crashes too.